# static casting from a base class to derived

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp, static-cast

There's something not clear to me i wish to put under your attention, please check those code snippets:

```
template< typename DerivedClass >
class construction_management
{
    city* this_city;
public:
    construction_management()
    {
        this_city = static_cast< city* >(this);
    }
    ~construction_management();
};
```

I removed intentionally all the not necessary code, please look at the constructor which make a static cast of the 'this' pointer to a type 'city', which is defined as below:

```
class city : public construction_management< city >
{

public:

public:
    city( const string& name, const string& owner );
};
```

The class is intentionally empty, since i think nothing it can contain is relevant here. Want i'm not able to understand at 100% is what is happening here, g++ 4.7.2 prints not warning or error during the compiling phase, and whenever i use the 'this_city' pointer i can access all the public members of city, the object itself looks consistent since all the variables are properly initialized and contain always valid data.

What i wish to know, is why this code does not work if i define construction_management as a plain non-template class? The cast fails due to a conversion tentative from const to non const pointer to city, why?

This is the error print:

```
game.hpp: In constructor 'city_manager::construction_management::construction_management()':
game.hpp:164:41: error: invalid static_cast from type 'city_manager::construction_management* const' to type 'city_manager::city*'
```

And why work if construction_management is a template? Is this a kind of CRTP?

Thank you all.

Comment: I would say this *is* CRTP. You're creating a template instantiation of the derived class with it's own base. AFAIK that's CRTP.

Answer (score 5):

It's CRTP and it works because of lazy template instantiation.

The line:

```
this_city = static_cast< city* >(this);
```

Requires `this` to be convertible to a `city*`. That does work if `city` is derived from `construction_management`. However, base classes must have complete declarations before derived classes, so there is only one way to write that:

```
//template code may or may not be present
class construction_management {...};
//maybe more code here
class city: public construction_management {...};
```

If the base class is not a template, it is instanced when the compiler first sees the code. Then the compiler runs into the constructor, it doesn't know at that point that `city` is derived from `construction_management` (or even what a `city` is, if it hasn't been declared as an incomplete type), and gives up.

However, if the base class is a template, it is instanced when inheritance is declared (somewhere around that time anyway, I'm not an expert on this). At that point, the compiler knows that `city` is derived from `construction_management<city>`, and everything works.

For the same reasons, it also works without a template if you move the constructor definition to a file which is compiled later (most likely from the .h to the .cpp).

Comment: Hum, is working fine if i put the code constructor in the cpp. My only  quandary now is about how does such kind of code looks like from a design and elegance perspective. I need to access some elements in city which are not allowed to be present as member in construction_management, as sake of example, a 'player_info' structure is incapsulated in city, but construction_management also need some of the information contained in that structure ( as also another class from which city inherit from ), that's why i use to have the this_city pointer in the base class.

Comment: It's pretty standard to put code in .cpp files, even more so when _it won't work otherwise_. The only time where you shouldn't do it at all is when writing templates (which is why the constructor code was in the header file in the original, templated version of your code).

Comment: My thought was about the useage of the pointer 'this_city' and that cast, shall i look at a different solution in you opinion, or is not as bad as i think? ( i dont know why, but somehow i try to avoid casting operations ).

Comment: @user1882090 Up to you. Some people prefer to avoid this kind of design. I don't care at all, sometimes it's more convenient (this case?), and sometimes you simply have to do it.